# html5: audio doesn't work with apache on my wamp server

Tags: audio

I downloaded able player, an accessible cross browser audio and video player from https://ableplayer.github.io/ableplayer/
Before downloading, I played some examples from github pages to see it in action with my screen reader. It works very fine, with internet explorer 11, google chrome and firefox.
So, i downloaded it and copied it in my localhost server. I use wamp server, apache, php and mysql.
Before playing from my localhost, I added on my .htaccess in root folder, all AddType directives suggested by able player github page.
When I try to play examples in demo folder, with internet explorer, my screen reader doesn't see audio player region and I can't play anything.
With google chrome, I can play, but I can't see playlist elements managed by able player.
So, I tried to make my own audio player without using ableplayer, without css, simple html5.
Now, I tried to play it with and without apache.
By opening index.html with internet explore, it sees audio region and play mp3.
If I point to localhost, where I put index.html, I can't see anything.
So I believe apache is the problem, but in apache log I can't see any error.
Does Some one has a suggestion? Something to modify in my .htaccess?
Thanks!

Comment: What extension does your video file has? Different browsers ignore some file types. mp4 should be a safe bet for video

Comment: I trying to play an mp3 and an mp4.

Answer (score 0):

I solved! Definitively was apache. I downloaded an .htaccess from github that works fine. Now I can play audio and video.